# PHP - using set_include_path correctly

Tags: php

I have been using set_include_path typically in the starting point of my applications to add the base directory of my packages for some time now.

Is this the way this should typically be used?

And how would you use it if you were integrating a new package into an existing system?

Comment: Your current use sounds pretty typical to me. What, exactly, do you mean by "integrate a new package into an existing system", though?

Comment: I am working with an existing ecommerce site which i cant fully integrate my code into - its kind of seperate but works with it.  I want to keep my code pretty organised and so wondered if using the set_include_path would work the same way.

Answer (score 7):

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path_you_want_to_add);
```